# Single runnable for accessing server, subclassed by different types of requests: how to ensure uniqueness?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, runnable, synchronized

Here is the one class that is meant to be responsible to communicating with the server:

```
public abstract class AbstractCommunicationChannel implements Runnable {
    static String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://0.0.0.0";

    private URL url;
    private JSONObject requestObject;
    private JSONObject responseObject;

    AbstractCommunicationChannel(URL url, JSONObject requestObject) {
        this.url = url;
        this.requestObject = requestObject;
    }

    /**
     * This is the general purpose tool for hitting the server and getting a response back.
     */
    public void run() {
        Log.i("requestObject", requestObject.toString());
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write(requestObject.toString());
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
            /* * */
            InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int result = bufferedInputStream.read();
            while (result != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write((byte) result);
                result = bufferedInputStream.read();
            }
            responseObject = new JSONObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8"));
            httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        processResponse(responseObject);
    }

    protected abstract void processResponse(JSONObject responseObject);
}
```

Here is an example subclass, responsible for a specific type of request:

```
public class LoginRequester extends AbstractCommunicationChannel {

    public LoginRequester(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        super(new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + ":0000/login"),
            new JSONObject().put("username", username).put("password", password));
    }

    @Override
    protected void processResponse(JSONObject responseObject) {
        try {
            if (responseObject.get("result").equals("valid")) {
                StartActivity.accessAccountActivity();
            }

            if (responseObject.get("result").equals("username")) {
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.startContext, "No such username exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (responseObject.get("result").equals("password")) {
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.startContext, "Invalid password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

For context, here is another:

```
public class CreateRequester extends AbstractCommunicationChannel {

    public CreateRequester(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        super(new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + ":8080/create"),
            new JSONObject().put("username", username).put("password", password));
    }

    @Override
    protected void processResponse(JSONObject responseObject) {
        try {
            if (responseObject.get("result").equals("success")) {
                StartActivity.accessAccountActivity();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.startContext, "ERROR!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is that there is only ever one entity that is able to make requests to the server, so is there some way to make that `AbstractCommunicationChannel` synchronized to make sure that there can't be two, or more, threads talking to the server at any one time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Class level lock in abstract class(if you use single class loader):

***Class level lock prevents multiple threads to enter in synchronized block in any of all available instances of the class on runtime.***

For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractCommunicationChannel implements Runnable {
   private static Object lock = new Object();

    public void run() {
      synchronized(lock){
        Log.i("requestObject", requestObject.toString());
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStreamWriter.write(requestObject.toString());
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
            /* * */
            InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int result = bufferedInputStream.read();
            while (result != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write((byte) result);
                result = bufferedInputStream.read();
            }
            responseObject = new JSONObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8"));
            httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
     }
        processResponse(responseObject);
    }
```

Comment: do I have to pass this `lock` object around in classes that call those runnables? what I was also recently thinking was, what if there's just a dedicated thread for accessing this functionality in each class that touches such requests, when we enter the class we execute the runnable on that thread and when we leave the class we kill the thread- what do you think of that?

Comment: The lock should be private in the AbstractClass, in this way its the responsibility of the AbstractClass to use this lock and you dont force the sbuclaccess to implement the logic around lock. You can do it as you propose but you will have to handle the threads which is little bit complicated. With the pattern I propose you can do this: CreateRequester request = new CreateRequest(....,...); CompletableFuture.runAsync(request); and the request will be executed in another thread, and so on.. Its easier than to implement only one thread that is able to run request.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, I'm sure it'll make more sense as I think about it more, but man, I wonder, would you have any interest in doing a google hangout together and talking thru the architecture wrt the threading model a bit? maybe on sunday or something